# What is so special about Jules Verne's works?

Tags: history

What differentiated Jules Verne from his fellow science-fiction peers at that time?  Is Jules Verne truly considered a science fiction writer, as some people see him, or more of an adventure writer?  Why is it that Verne holds a noted place in the history of science fiction and fantasy?

This isn't a homework question, I'm just curious.  I've read his works along with HG Wells work and have trouble seeing any differences between them.  Is there something he used to separate his own work from others (besides language), style, plot devices, narrative?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What *is* special about Jules Verne that makes you ask this question?

Comment: Which peers, exactly, would you be comparing him to? Wells wasn't one of his peers until late in his life.

Comment: To answer my own question in part, Poe was roughly contemporaneous before his untimely death and also wrote in speculative fields at time. But I don't think I've read any of his work that seemed science fictiony, so it is hard for me to compare them.

Comment: @dmckee: Poe is considered by many to be the Father of Science Fiction.  Many of his stories had strong elements of SF.  And Verne was enamoured with Poe, as were many of the French writers of Verne's time and even wrote an ending to Poe's unfinished _The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym of Nantucket_.  And Verne, and others, considered Poe a leader and predecessor who opened the doors for them.  While there is time overlap, in terms of effect of what they did, Poe came first.

Comment: @Jimmey Chen: Both Wells and Verne are giants in the field.  Saying Verne was great does not make Wells not-great.

Comment: "I've read his works along with HG Wells work and have trouble seeing any differences between them." In fairness, Jules Verne wrote in French. Perhaps you read bad translations.

Comment: @MarkBeadles That's an important point about Verne: from what I heard, he has been generally poorly translated into English. There's also a skewed perception, in that his non-sf works are less well-known in English. [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne) presents Verne as a science fiction writer, while [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne) presents him as an adventure and science-fiction writer; this reflects the different perception of his œuvre in France and in English-speaking countries.

Comment: [Ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/should-this-question-be-closed)

Comment: I've refocused the question.  I'm not sure if this even addresses the flaws, but at least I hope I can repair in some way.  If anyone else could help, that'd be great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Jules Verne was one of the first.  At that point, the term "science fiction" was not even coined (and it was decades before Hugo Gernsback would come up with the term "scientifiction").  I'm not sure if the term "Speculative Fiction" was even in use.

But before Verne, there was Edgar Allan Poe (a man from my own home town!).  Many consider him the Father of Science fiction for stories of his like *Descent into the Maelstrom*, where he correctly described the effects of objects being pulled into a whirlpool, or *MS Found in a Bottle*, which included scenes based on the pop-science belief of the time that the Earth was probably hollow.  And elements of his one novel, *The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym of Nantucket* also have science fiction connections.  But Poe believed in short stories.  While many stories of his were scientifically accurate (like *The Conversation of Eiros and Charmion*, which accurately described a world catching on fire when there was too much oxygen), a short story can do little more than work with one concept and the genre was still too new for him to introduce depth of character and story along with multiple concepts.

Then came Verne.  He wasn't the first and many will say he wasn't the best, but he picked up where Poe left off.  Verne, like many French writers (and readers) of his time idolized Poe.  (And while there is some overlap in time, Poe's work essentially predated Verne's.)  He was extremely impressed with his unfinished and somewhat speculative adventure novel *The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym of Nantucket*.  I remember reading an article where Verne spoke of Poe with reverence and said something like, "Perhaps some day we'll have a writer good enough to finish the story for Mr. Poe.  Alas, though, this task would be for one greater than I."  (Yes, it was in flowery prose.)

Verne wrote long stories that could develop a concept more.  One of the most famous is *Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea*, which was a about a submarine.  While submarines were not new, the idea that people could live in one for an extended time and that it could cross oceans was new.  In this book, Verne explored not just the idea of "it's a big underwater ship," but went farther, including scenes like the famous fight with the giant squid, farming under water, and Captain Nemo's ability to attack normal seagoing vessels.

Verne also wrote about airships and the ability to try to rule the Earth from one, and wrote about making a spaceship that would make the almost unimaginable journey *From the Earth to the Moon*.  In this case, as with others, he had worked out a lot of the details.  He was aware of the Moon's orbit and that the ship would best be launched in an area not too far away from the equator and was also aware that waste thrown out of the capsule would be travelling along with the capsule, through space, since nothing would push it in another direction.

Whether Verne was great or special is a subjective view.  I don't think people would say he was better than Wells - I've never seen anyone ranking either of them higher than the other.  But one of them being great does not make the other any the less of a master.

Verne created characters to fit in the fantastic settings he created, such as the mysterious Captain Nemo, or Lars, the faithful helper in *Journey to the Center of the Earth*, who rarely spoke.  So we wanted to read his stories and find out who these people were and what happened to them.

It's not one factor that makes Verne's work great, but many.  He was essentially the first to write longer works like this, he made the science interesting, and he had more than just cardboard characters.  He took what the Father of Science Fiction left him and expanded greatly on it.

Comment: "Perhaps some day we'll have a writer good enough to finish the story for Mr. Poe. Alas, though, this task would be for one greater than I." Do you happen to know whether it was before or after he did?

Comment: Yes.  I don't remember the exact timing, but Verne wrote that sometime after Poe died, as I recall, and while he still didn't think he was up to the task - remember, he really looked up to Poe!